# Masm invoke createfile does not work

Tags: winapi, assembly, masm, createfile, irvine32

I am trying to create a file under C:\ in Masm code. 
but can never success. I don't know where is wrong with the code.

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc


.data
fileName BYTE "C:\\haha.txt",0
fileHandle HANDLE ?

.code

main PROC

INVOKE CreateFile,
ADDR filename, GENERIC_WRITE, DO_NOT_SHARE, null, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,0


exit
main ENDP
END main
```

if I change the

```
fileName BYTE "haha.txt",0
```

it will success write the file haha.txt on the program's folder.
i dont understand why it does not write out to C:\
also, i am using visual studio 2013 and i run the program by run it under debug,start without debugging.

Comment: Works here (WinXP). You don't need to double the backslash since the backslash has no special meaning in MASM or ML. I guess it has something to do with the privileges. [Look here](http://www.mkyong.com/computer-tips/cant-create-file-in-the-c-drive-root-directory-windows-8/) (I didn't verify the solution).

Comment: that works too, but it required to reboot and I'm trying to write a simple virus, so i do not want to restart the user's computer. Thank You for your help, it's a good answer and solution ! learned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a permission problem. If you run the program as administrator, you will see that the file is created.
Just tested it with your code and it works.

Comment: The double '\\' are not needed, I was wrong on that.

Comment: do you know how do I run it in administrator without user's attention? like what I'm saying is if i apply it to a virus, can I say something in the code to make it everything user run it, it will be under administrator.

Comment: Not that I know of, unless you carry it with an exploit.